# MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6, python3.7 installation Install Certificate.command results in SSLError

Tags: python, openssl, anaconda, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

After installing python 3.7 from python.org, running the Install Certificate.command resulted in the below error. Please, can you provide some guidance? Why does Install Certificate.command result in error?

[Some background]
Tried to install python via anaconda, brew and python.org, even installing version 3.6.6, hoping I could get one of them to work. Each installation resulted in ssl certification errors when I tried to install a package. See further below for example error from current python 3.7 installation.

I read every page with any reference to openssl errors and followed every instruction. That last one probably has done more damage to my machine tbh. I installed, uninstalled and reinstalled from each of anaconda, brew and python.org, deleting and cleaning a bunch of folders along the way, trying to make a clean installation. Along the way, I even managed to delete pip, wheel and setuptools from site-directories folder of the apple preinstalled python version. So all in all, after a week of python installation hell, I am totally stuck.

```
 Collecting certifi
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/certifi/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/certifi/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/certifi/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/certifi/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/certifi/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/certifi/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/certifi/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for certifi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 44, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 25, in main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7', '-E', '-s', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'certifi']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

`pip3 install numpy` results in the below error

```
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

---

EDIT post @newbie comment

Based on the most upvoted answer in that post, I tried the following:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1604k  100 1604k    0     0   188k      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--  148k

$ python3 get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip

$ pip3 search numpy
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /pypi
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 356, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 359, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more times]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 141, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/search.py", line 48, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/search.py", line 65, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 788, in request
    headers=headers, stream=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 396, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 511, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))
```

===========
EDIT2 : searched for all locations where copies of openssl.cnf file exists. Does this seem right?

```
$ mdfind openssl.cnf
/usr/local/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf
/opt/vagrant/embedded/ssl/openssl.cnf
/opt/vagrant/embedded/ssl/openssl.cnf.dist
/private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
/opt/vagrant/embedded/ssl/misc/CA.pl
```

Comment: just tried with osx 10.13.6 and python3.7 and everything is fine so the problem is not general. check if this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi) contains the solution.

Comment: @newbie agree. Are there any system files or other applications/installations the python3.7 installation would depend on to work? Wondering if it is at all possible to work out what I could have deleted.

Comment: What is the output of this command for you: `python3 -c "import pip._vendor.certifi as c; print(c.where())"`. It is supposed to give the path to a `cacert.pem` file -- does that file exist on your machine?

Comment: @Reiner Torenbeek, result of the command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=appdata#config-file as per this page I should have pip.conf at one of these locations: 'Site-wide' at /Library/Application Support/pip. There is no pip directory there. 'Per-user' in location $HOME/Library/Application Support/pip or $HOME/.config/pip. There is no pip directory [and consequently no pip.conf file] in any of these locations. The command mdfind pip.conf returns nothing!

Answer (score 1):

wanted to answer my own question as I seem to have fixed most of the issues. The solution:

1. Created a pip directory and then a pip.conf file in $HOME/Library/Application Support
2. To the pip.conf added code

   [global]
       trusted-host = pypi.python.org
                      pypi.org
                      files.pythonhosted.org
3. Started installing using

   $ pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip
4. Then tried pip install  which worked, so used that to install numpy, pandas, geopy etc.
5. Successfully ran the Install CertificateCommand file in Applications/Python 3.7

Results:

1. Installation via pip is working.
2. Spyder3 is working
3. Python 3.7 is working
4. numpy, pandas, matplotlib, geopy are working
5. Jupyter notebook is working

Outstanding: Still getting GeocoderServiceError and Brew doctor says vim missing python. Will raise separate questions for these.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run Install Certificate.command.
You should reinstall Xcode command line tools that contains Python.

```sh
pip3 uninstall -y -r <(pip requests certifi)
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3

sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -r

python3 -m pip install --user certifi
python3 -m pip install --user requests
```