# MacOS High OSierra 10.13.6, Python3.7, GeocoderServiceError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, geopy

I recently installed python 3.7 on macOS High OSierra and spent ages trying to get it working. That question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154682/macos-high-sierra-10-13-6-python3-7-installation-install-certificate-command-re?noredirect=1#comment91267651_52154682). Currently I am having problems with the below code and wondered if anyone can help.

```
import geopy
geocoder = geopy.geocoders.GoogleV3(domain = "maps.google.co.uk")
geocoder.geocode("Cambridge", exactly_one = False)
```

Results in the following error:

> SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py
>   in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1316
>   h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
>   -> 1317                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1318
>   except OSError as err: # timeout error
>
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py
> >     in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)    1228
> >     """Send a complete request to the server."""
> >     -> 1229         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)    1230
> >
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py
> >     in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
> >     1274             body = _encode(body, 'body')
> >     -> 1275         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)    1276
> >
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py
> >     in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)    1223
> >     raise CannotSendHeader()
> >     -> 1224         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)    1225
> >
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py
> >     in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)    1015
> >     del self._buffer[:]
> >     -> 1016         self.send(msg)    1017
> >
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py
> >     in send(self, data)
> >         955             if self.auto_open:
> >     --> 956                 self.connect()
> >         957             else:
> >
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py
> >     in connect(self)    1391             self.sock =
> >     self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
> >     -> 1392                                                   server_hostname=server_hostname)    1393
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py
>   in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect,
>   suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
>       411             context=self,
>   --> 412             session=session
>       413         )
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py
>   in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect,
>   suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
>       849                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for
>   non-blocking sockets")
>   --> 850                     self.do_handshake()
>       851             except (OSError, ValueError):
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py
>   in do_handshake(self, block)    1107
>   self.settimeout(None)
>   -> 1108             self._sslobj.do_handshake()    1109         finally:
>
> > SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate
> >     chain (_ssl.c:1045)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py
>   in _call_geocoder(self, url, timeout, raw, requester, deserializer,
>   **kwargs)
>       314         try:
>   --> 315             page = requester(req, timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
>       316         except Exception as error:
>
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py
> >     in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
> >         524 
> >     --> 525         response = self._open(req, data)
> >         526
> >
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py
> >     in _open(self, req, data)
> >         542         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
> >     --> 543                                   '_open', req)
> >         544         if result:
> >
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py
> >     in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
> >         502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
> >     --> 503             result = func(*args)
> >         504             if result is not None:
> >
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py
> >     in https_open(self, req)    1359             return
> >     self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
> >     -> 1360                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)    1361
> >
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py
> >     in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1318
> >     except OSError as err: # timeout error
> >     -> 1319                 raise URLError(err)    1320             r = h.getresponse()
>
> URLError:
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> GeocoderServiceError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 geocoder.geocode("Cambridge", exactly_one = False)
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/googlev3.py
>   in geocode(self, query, exactly_one, timeout, bounds, region,
>   components, language, sensor)
>       240         logger.debug("%s.geocode: %s", self.**class**.**name**, url)
>       241         return self._parse_json(
>   --> 242             self._call_geocoder(url, timeout=timeout), exactly_one
>       243         )
>       244
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py
>   in _call_geocoder(self, url, timeout, raw, requester, deserializer,
>   **kwargs)
>       340                 if "timed out" in message:
>       341                     raise GeocoderTimedOut('Service timed out')
>   --> 342             raise GeocoderServiceError(message)
>       343 
>       344         if hasattr(page, 'getcode'):
>
> GeocoderServiceError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain
>   (_ssl.c:1045)

Comment: Are you behind some kind of proxy? Because "maps.google.co.uk" is certainly not using a self signed certificate and yet you get error message "certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Comment: I searched for how to check if I am behind a proxy => In Google Chrome browser go to advanced settings -> Network -> Proxies and check if any of the options are ticked. They were all unticked. Does this answer your question? Or, is there another way to find if I am behind some proxy? Thanks

Comment: First check from your Python code to which IP addresses `maps.google.co.uk` does resolve, and if they are from Google really. Then your Python code may be using a proxy even if Chrome is not using one. Also did you try with any other name? Does the result change if you change the network to which your computer is attached to?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following link: [here](https://timonweb.com/tutorials/fixing-certificate_verify_failed-error-when-trying-requests_html-out-on-mac/)

I was able to get it working by running the second command on that page:

`open /Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command`